# Inline image in dynamic text

Tags: html, css, actionscript-3, flash

I am working on a chat application using AS3. I am new to AS and flash. I want to add smilies in the chat. So when a user types ":p" i want to replace it with an image in his text message. I simply used image tag to do this. However, image does not show inline. It shows in the next line.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Example:
Currently -> this is my chat
image here

Desired results -> this is my "image here" chat

Sample code

```
var abc:String="This is my :p chat";
abc.replace(":p", "<img src='url of the image' height='10' width='10'>"
```

Comment: I didn't try anything fancy. I have added the sample code snippet in the question.

Comment: See my answer below and please accept the answer if and only if it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
img{
  display: inline;
}
```

I am assuming you already know about loading stylesheets via AS3?

UPDATE:

Something like this should work:

```
var style:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
style.parseCSS("img{ display: inline; }");

// IMPORTANT: tf is whatever TextField instance you are using
tf.styleSheet = style;
var str:String = "<p>This is my :p chat</p>";
tf.htmlText = str.replace(":p", "<img src='url of the image' height='10' width='10'>");
```

Comment: Nope, I didn't try this and I don't know about CSS in AS3. I am novice to AS. Could you please give me more details? Sample code would be awesome!

Comment: All you need to do is load a stylesheet (containing the above one rule) and apply it to the text fields in question. There are a lot of places to see this in action, here is one http://grfxguru.wordpress.com/2008/05/28/load-an-external-css-file-using-actionscript-3-sample-code/

Comment: I tried your code but it is not working. It is still showing the image in the next line.

Comment: Check the above. If it doesn't work, then that's about all I can test without Flash

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var _message = "Good to see u :) how are you";
chatTxt.htmlText = doReplace(_message);
function doReplace(msg):String
{
    var _str = refDocument._baseURL + "/tool/assets/emotion/";
    var _search:Array = [":)",";)"];
    var _replace:Array = ["<img width='20' height='20' src='smile.png'>","<img width='20' height='20' src='wink.png'>"];
    for (var i:int=0; i<_search.length; i++)
    {
        msg = msg.split(_search[i]).join(_replace[i]);
    }
    return msg;
}
```

make sure chatTxt is TLF text